# Ajax Jquery PUT request doesn't work

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I am trying to send an Ajax PUT request using jQuery to my server but when I `console.log` the data I get back through my success function, I get the very same data I am trying to update.

Here my Ajax request:

```
$(".plus-button").on("click", function() {

    var handler = $(this).siblings(".editIngredientForm");

    var formData = {
        photoName: handler.children("#numberOfItems").prevObject[0][0]["value"],
        name: handler.children("#numberOfItems").prevObject[0][1]["value"],

        // Add + 1 to number of items in ingredient to account for the clicking on plus sign
        number: Number(handler.children("#numberOfItems").prevObject[0][2]["value"]) + 1,
    };

    var actionUrl = $(this).siblings(".editIngredientForm").attr("action");
    // console.log(formData);     

    $.ajax({
        url: actionUrl,
        data: formData,
        type: "PUT",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
```

And here's the backend route (Node JS) that handles updates:

```
app.put("/inventory/:id", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Ingredient.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.item, { new: true }, function(err, updatedIngredient) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (req.xhr) {
                res.json(updatedIngredient);
            } else {
                req.flash("success", "You successfully updated the Ingredient's info");
                res.redirect("/inventory/" + req.params.id);
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: does `req.body.item` have a value?

Comment: Make sure you have installed body-parser and configure the middleware app.use(body.json());

Comment: i dont know node.js but i dont see where you changed the returned value to the updated one.

Comment: @RolandStarke When I console.log(req.body.item)  after else{ ,nothing is printed .

Comment: @santoshsingh Body-parser is installed and I added app.use(bodyParser.json()), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @bresleveloper The update route is what should change it. Precisely this:  Ingredient.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.item, { new: true }, function(err, updatedIngredient) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (req.xhr) {
                res.json(updatedIngredient);
            } else {
                req.flash("success", "You successfully updated the Ingredient's info");
                res.redirect("/inventory/" + req.params.id);
            }
        }
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that I found eventually:

```
$(".plus-button").on("click", function(){

    var handler = $(this).siblings(".editIngredientForm");
    var oldNumber = handler.find('input[name="item[number]"]').val();
    var newNumber = Number(oldNumber) + 1;
    var numberOfIngredient = $(this).parent("#changeQuantitiesButtons").siblings("#state-of-inventory").children("#number-of-ingredient");
    handler.find('input[name="item[number]"]').val(newNumber);

    var formData= handler.serialize();
    var actionUrl = $(this).siblings(".editIngredientForm").attr("action");   

    $.ajax({
        url:actionUrl,        
        data:formData,
        type:"PUT",              
        success: function(data){
           numberOfIngredient.html(newNumber);
        }
    })
});
```

Instead of sending data directly through an Ajax put request and then modifying the value in the form, what I did is change the value in the form and the sending the form data(that I serialized with .serialize() ) through the request.

Hope it will help someone.